# Quotient categories and essential extension

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $A$ be a right Noetherian positively graded ring. Let $Gr(A)$ be the category of right graded $A$-modules, and $Tors(A)$ be the full subcategory of $Gr(A)$ of torsion modules. Let $QGr(A)$ be the quotient category $Gr(A)/Tors(A)$ and $\pi:Gr(A)\to QGr(A)$ the canonical projection. It is known that $\pi$ preserves injective envelopes.

Does $\pi$ preserves essential extensions? Any comments will be grateful.

Comment: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1962__90_/BSMF_1962__90__323_0/BSMF_1962__90__323_0.pdf may help. There is a nice section about quotient categories including treatment about essential extensions and injective envelopes.

Comment: Since the torsion submodule of injective modules is injective, one can obtain that π preserves injective envelopes. However I haven't found any answer in the paper http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1962__90_/BSMF_1962__90__323_0/BSMF_1962__90__323_0.pdf